# linux correct syntax to pass custom directory for libstdc++.so.6 via config

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

I have a custom compiled gcc 5.4.0 with the following folder structure `/home/gccprefix/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`.

So far compiling has been going well passing extra flags via configure such as `CC=/home/gccprfix/bin/gcc CFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-Wfatal-errors CFLAGS=-I/home/gccprefix/header/tr1`.

But now I have it a problem compiling cairo with `/home/gccprefix/bin/ragel`. To compile I have a bash script with the flags allocated as a variable, such as

```
MYFLAGS="CC=/home/gccprfix/bin/gcc CFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-Wfatal-errors CFLAGS=-I/home/gccprefix/header/tr1"
.../configure ${MYFLAGS}
```

Ragel was compiled with the `/home/gccprefix/bin/gcc` as above with no errors.

However during `make` for cairo, I get

```
ragel: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ragel)
```

This is due to gcc finding the default `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`. So following several threads on SO I believe I need to extend the flags passed to configure.

What is the correct syntax

```
`CFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,/home/gccprefix/lib64`
```

or do I drop the `CFLAGS=`

```
`-Wl,-rpath,/home/gccprefix/lib64`
```

Using the first option with `CFLAGS=` the new `libstdc++.so.6` is not passed and the same error occurs, using the send without a `CFLAGS` just gives an error

```
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--Wl,-rpath,/home/gccprefix/lib64'
```

So what prefix do I use?

Comment: You had double dashes `configure: error: unrecognized option: --Wl,-rpath,/home/gccprefix/lib64`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be

```
./configure ... LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/home/gccprefix/lib64
```

Looking at the generated Makefiles, you could probably get away with CXXFLAGS but not with CFLAGS which are not used at all for a C++-only project.

Note `CFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-Wfatal-errors CFLAGS=-I...` is pointless, only `-I...` will be passed to the compiler, and only to a C compiler. Try `CXXFLAGS="-fPIC -Wfatal-errors -I..."` instead, making sure configure gets that as a single argument. Passing it via MYFLAGS probably won't work.